# Javascript - JQuery append function and using quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a large append function in my code. In this append function, i am populating an textarea with some text. In this text, I can also have quotes (") and this is causing problems because my append function will interprete those quotes as breaking quotes, and it should not.

Do you have an ideao on how to escape those quotes? Thank you.

EDIT: Here is my append function:

```
$('#add_affiliation').append(
            '<div id="affiliation_'+affiliation_id+'title" class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">'+
                '<span id="affiliation_title'+affiliation_id+'" class="ui-dialog-title">Affiliation '+affiliation_id+'</span>'+
                '<a href="#delete_affiliation" id="delete_affiliation_'+affiliation_id+'" onclick="deleteAffiliation(\''+affiliation_id+'\');" >'+
                    '<img style="float:right" src="/css/images/delete_affiliation.png" />'+
                '</a>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div id="affiliation_'+affiliation_id+'content" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">'+
                '<label for="add_affiliations"></label>'+
                '<div id="add_affiliation_'+affiliation_id+'" style="overflow: hidden" class="element">'+
                    '<table id="affiliation_table" style="table-layout:fixed;">'+
                    '<tbody>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<td style="height:30px; width:65px;" align="right"><font size="2"><b>N°:</b></font></td>'+
                            '<td align="left" style="height:30px; width:700px;">'+
                                '<input type="text" name="number"; id="number'+affiliation_id+'"; value="'+article_affiliations[i].number+'" />'+
                            '</td>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<td style="height:30px; width:65px;" align="right"><font size="2"><b>Affiliation:</b></font></td>'+
                            '<td align="left" style="height:30px; width:700px;">'+
                                '<input type="text" name="affiliation" id="affiliation'+affiliation_id+'" value="'+article_affiliations[i].name+'" style="width: 100%;" />'+
                            '</td>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                        '<tr>'+
                            '<td style="height:30px; width:65px;" align="right"><font size="2"><b>Country:</b></font></td>'+
                            '<td align="left" style="height:30px; width:700px;">'+
                            '<select id="country'+affiliation_id+'";></select>'+
                            '<img style="vertical-align:bottom; " src="/css/images/Warning.png"; id="country_warning'+affiliation_id+'"; width="20px"; height="20px"; alt="-"; />'+
                            '<span id="country_warning_message'+affiliation_id+'" style="visibility:hidden; color:red;"></span>'+
                            '</td>'+
                        '</tr>'+
                    '</tbody>'+
                '</table>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>');
```

Comment: Why not find the textarea after the append and populate it using .val() ?

Comment: @Jack, this could work, I can try this.

Comment: @Milos - Why aren't you using a more oop approach to this such as taking advantage of `document.createElement`, breaking some of this creation into functions to reduce redundant code, and leveraging your server side control (assuming this is some sort of framework).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would basically do the regular append *without* giving any values and then use `.find(selector).val(value)` on each element:

```
$('<div id="affiliation_'+affiliation_id+'title" class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">'+
            '<span id="affiliation_title'+affiliation_id+'" class="ui-dialog-title">Affiliation '+affiliation_id+'</span>'+
            '<a href="#delete_affiliation" id="delete_affiliation_'+affiliation_id+'" onclick="deleteAffiliation(\''+affiliation_id+'\');" >'+
                '<img style="float:right" src="/css/images/delete_affiliation.png" />'+
            '</a>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div id="affiliation_'+affiliation_id+'content" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">'+
            '<label for="add_affiliations"></label>'+
            '<div id="add_affiliation_'+affiliation_id+'" style="overflow: hidden" class="element">'+
                '<table id="affiliation_table" style="table-layout:fixed;">'+
                '<tbody>'+
                    '<tr>'+
                        '<td style="height:30px; width:65px;" align="right"><font size="2"><b>N°:</b></font></td>'+
                        '<td align="left" style="height:30px; width:700px;">'+
                            '<input type="text" name="number"; id="number'+affiliation_id+'"; value="" />'+
                        '</td>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                    '<tr>'+
                        '<td style="height:30px; width:65px;" align="right"><font size="2"><b>Affiliation:</b></font></td>'+
                        '<td align="left" style="height:30px; width:700px;">'+
                            '<input type="text" name="affiliation" id="affiliation'+affiliation_id+'" value="" style="width: 100%;" />'+
                        '</td>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                    '<tr>'+
                        '<td style="height:30px; width:65px;" align="right"><font size="2"><b>Country:</b></font></td>'+
                        '<td align="left" style="height:30px; width:700px;">'+
                        '<select id="country'+affiliation_id+'";></select>'+
                        '<img style="vertical-align:bottom; " src="/css/images/Warning.png"; id="country_warning'+affiliation_id+'"; width="20px"; height="20px"; alt="-"; />'+
                        '<span id="country_warning_message'+affiliation_id+'" style="visibility:hidden; color:red;"></span>'+
                        '</td>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                '</tbody>'+
            '</table>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>')
    .find('#number' + affiliation_id)
        .val(article_affiliations[i].number)
        .end()
    .find('#affiliation' + affiliation_id)
        .val(article_affiliations[i].name)
        .end()
    .appendTo('#add_affiliation')
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rgvaw/)

Comment: thank you. But what is the `$('<the huge fragment you have but without values>')` ? Where should I put this code?

Comment: @Milos Whatever you had in your `.append()` originally.

Comment: so at the end of my append (see my question), I should add `.find('#number' + aff`.... ?

Comment: @Milos No, whatever you have in your `.append()` should go into `$()` in my answer, but leaving the values blank.

Comment: what i did is using `document.getElementById(...)` and then with .value assigning the value to my textarea. And it works.

Comment: I have tryed this before but without success. Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate this.

Comment: @Milos Not sure what you did wrong, but it works in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rgvaw/)

Comment: hm, yes, that's strange, when I tried I got a javascript error but haven't tryed to look deaper in, I changed this method by document.getElementById(...) and it works like a charm now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a backlash before the quotes **\"**  or use single quotes to encompass your string **' " '**

Remember strings can be delimited by single quotes (in which case double quoutes inside them don't need to be escaped), or double quotes (in which case single quoutes don't need to be escaped).

Additionally, you can use something like

```
var doubleQuoutesEscaped = originalString.split('"').join('\\"');
var singleQuoutesEscaped = originalString.split("'").join("\\'");
```

Comment: this will not resolve my problem. Pleaase, se the append function I added in my question. The append function is complex and I am using single quotes to encompass the string. The string in question is rticle_affiliations[i].name

Comment: For your edited question: But what if I have to escape double quotes and single quotes. Maybe the best solution is to use a function which will replace single and double quotes with a backslash before ?

Comment: I made a small edit, try the function to replace the quotes with escaped characters.

Comment: thank you. I gived you +1 but i think Jack's approach is more suitable,